# Disable "Upload" in Jupyter notebook

Tags: amazon-ec2, file-upload, jupyter-notebook

I am using Amazon EC2 AMI deep learning. 
how can I revoke permission of uploading a file in jupyter notebook? Is there any way I can deny user from uploading any new files from their local machine?

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue on the jupyter github: 
https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/293

A way to disable downloading is described here:
https://ujjwalbhardwaj.me/post/disable-download-button-on-the-sagemaker-jupyter-notebook

I haven't tested it myself, but I can image that overriding the *files_handler_class* with *None* in the latter example could also prevent uploads.

```
c.ContentsManager.files_handler_class = None
```

Answer (score 0):

About three years after Logiza DevOps' answer: this is *still* an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/7451), albeit a different one (#7451). The discussion revolves around making uploads extension-based so that they can be disabled. The problem is that it is not sufficient to "make the Upload button disappear" because it is also possible to upload a file by simply dragging and dropping it over the notebook's File manager. In short, this is complicated :-(

What's more: even if you could block file uploads, the user can still edit notebooks and other files through the Web GUI, so it's possible for instance to start some long-running CPU-intensive calculations on your notebook server. I think you have no other choice but to trust your notebook users...

Slightly off-topic: as regards disabling *downloads*, there is now a Jupyter extension-based solution:

```
jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/docmanager-extension:download
jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/filebrowser-extension:download
pip3 uninstall -y nbconvert
```

The `nbconvert` removal is necessary to prevent notebook conversion to PDF for instance.